# Simple file writing with ostream_iterator creates file, but doesn't write

Tags: c++, file, c++11

I have a really simple code to create a text file called "Input.txt", and write to it using ostream_iterator:

```
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ofstream os{ "Input.txt" }; 
    ostream_iterator<int> oo{ os,"," };

    vector<int> ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        ints.push_back(i);
    }

    unique_copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), oo);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above creates a "Input.txt", but there is nothing written to it. Am I missing something really obvious and fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not flushing the stream to disk before calling `system()`.

You can explicitly `flush()` or `close()` the stream:

```
int main() {
    ofstream os{ "Input.txt" };
    ostream_iterator<int> oo{ os,"," };

    vector<int> ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ints.push_back(i);
    }

    unique_copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), oo);

    os.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can put scoping braces around the stream so it goes out of scope sooner.

```
int main() {
    {
    ofstream os{ "Input.txt" };
    ostream_iterator<int> oo{ os,"," };

    vector<int> ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        ints.push_back(i);
    }

    unique_copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), oo);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was because I had "System("PAUSE")" in the code, blocking the output stream going into the file. This is the working code:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream os{ "Input.txt" }; // output stream for file "to"
    ostream_iterator<int> oo{ os,"," };

    vector<int> ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        ints.push_back(i);
    }

    unique_copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), oo);
    return 0;
}
```

Can't believe I missed this....